# Control fLOw in Load event, VB.NET desktop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

i have this code on my dialog box:

```
Private Sub DAddSupplier_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim objProveedores As New AR.CMP.ControlCatalogo()
    Dim dvClases, dvEstados As DataView

    dvClases = objProveedores.ListarClasesProveedor()

    If dvClases IsNot Nothing AndAlso dvClases.Count > 0 Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To dvClases.Count
            cmbClase.Items.Add(dvClases(i)("Class"))
        Next

    End If
    'reach until here the debugger 
    dvEstados = objProveedores.ListarEstadosProveedor()

    If dvEstados IsNot Nothing AndAlso dvEstados.Count > 0 Then

        For j As Integer = 0 To dvEstados.Count
            cmbEstado.Items.Add(dvEstados(j)("Name"))
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

but only reach the first block of code the second it is ignored unless the first get commented, why this behavior?

Comment: Probably because it throws an exception, look in the Output window.  The debugger won't stop when you're on a 64-bit operating system and your program is forced to run in 32-bit mode.  Several fixes for this but one is the obvious choice, this code does *not* belong in the Load event.  Put it in the constructor instead.  You'll now see the exception.

Comment: aLRight!, thanks I put it after initializationComponent and it works, but this is a comment i cannot give away points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it after the initializationComponent call and it will work